# How to remove all unicode representations in python

Tags: python, unicode, ascii

I am trying to remove all representations of special characters in my document, for example part of the document says: "world\u2019s", when I split this it gives `['world', '\u2019', 's']` but I need only the word(unicode and 's' removed). 
I am already removing all punctuation and this works on the actual punctuation that are shown normally not on these unicode representations.
And I have also tried to use regex to match everything that begins with a '\' but that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re

string = "world\u2019s"

print (re.sub(r"\b([^\s]+)\\([^\s]+)\b",r'\1',str(string.encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace'), 'ascii')))
```

Output:

```
world
```

You can apply this to your whole string document, should be working.

```
import re

string = "world\u2019s h\u2018e"

print (re.sub(r"\b([^\s]+)\\([^\s]+)\b",r'\1',str(string.encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace'), 'ascii')))
```

Output:

```
world h
```

Comment: not working in all case: string = "world\u2019s h\u2018e" => world\u2019s h :)